# Trimming CSV column not working

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file

```
A;B
FR0001  ; TOTO
FR0002  ; TITI
```

I want to trim column A

```
$csv=Import-Csv "test_trim.csv" -delimiter ";" | %{$_.A = ($_.A).Trim()}
```

But `$csv` is empty why ?

Comment: You are not outputting _anything_ to be captured. `%{$_.A = ($_.A).Trim(); $_}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$csv` will capture all of the *output* of your command. Of which there currently is none. If you changed the line to:

```
Import-Csv "test_trim.csv" -delimiter ";" | %{$_.A = ($_.A).Trim()}
```

You would see nothing on the console because there is no output. You need to output the updated object back to the pipe so that it will be captured by `$csv`

```
$csv = Import-Csv "test_trim.csv" -delimiter ";" | ForEach-Object{$_.A = ($_.A).Trim(); $_}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$csv=Import-Csv "test_trim.csv" -delimiter ";" | %{$_.A = ($_.A).Trim(); $_}
```

Powershell will by default return the result of last operation, so make the last operation your object.

Comment: _Powershell will by default return the result of last operation_ is not entirely accurate. You could ruin the object by changing the loop. `%{"test";$_.A = ($_.A).Trim(); $_}`. PowerShell typically attempt to use all output on the stream that it can. The way it handles it can sometimes be the challenge.